# IN Mysql Function how can return more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL.I able get more row in MySQL procedure but not in function . I want to write the function by returning values more than one row .  I attach my partial code:

```
drop function if exists test_splitfn;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE Function test_splitfn( sSepar VARCHAR(255), saVal TEXT )
Returns @MyTable table 
body:

BEGIN

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS lib_Explode;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lib_Explode(
    pos int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    val VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (pos)
  ) ENGINE=Memory COMMENT='Explode() results.';

  IF sSepar IS NULL OR saVal IS NULL THEN LEAVE body; END IF;

  SET @saTail = saVal;
  SET @iSeparLen = LENGTH( sSepar );

  create_layers:
  WHILE @saTail != '' DO

    # Get the next value
    SET @sHead = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@saTail, sSepar, 1);
    SET @saTail = SUBSTRING( @saTail, LENGTH(@sHead) + 1 + @iSeparLen );
    INSERT INTO lib_Explode SET val = @sHead;

  END WHILE;

     Insert @MyTable
      SELECT val  FROM lib_Explode;


    return @MyTable;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL function  you can't able to return the table..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS test_splitfn;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE test_splitfn (IN sSepar VARCHAR(255), saVal TEXT)
body:BEGIN

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS lib_Explode;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lib_Explode(
        pos int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
        val VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (pos)
    ) ENGINE=Memory COMMENT='Explode() results.';

    IF sSepar IS NULL OR saVal IS NULL THEN
        LEAVE body;
    END IF;

    SET @saTail = saVal;
    SET @iSeparLen = LENGTH( sSepar );

    WHILE (@saTail != '') DO
        SET @sHead = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@saTail, sSepar, 1);
        SET @saTail = SUBSTRING( @saTail, LENGTH(@sHead) + 1 + @iSeparLen );
        INSERT INTO lib_Explode SET val = @sHead;
    END WHILE;

    SELECT val FROM lib_Explode;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: using  separator  the value is separated and stored in table lib_Explode . its working fine . After END WHILE I try to return whole table but not able to create the function

Comment: I have massively edited my answer, please look on it again by reloading the page.

Comment: Its not working .I think function must use return.But if we use this concept in procedure means working.. I need the same concept  in function. Give some idea to finish this

Comment: Edited my answer once again, please try.

Comment: Thanks for helping but Yuriy  u are created in **procedure** i want this concept in function